# How to invite friends to the Facebook application that is not a game?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have 'Apps for pages' application. I use C# and Facebook javascript SDK. 
I would like to call the Facebook dialog for inviting friends.

This used to work with FB.ui method 'apprequests'. 
Now this is depreciated. 'apprequests' are available only to games. My application is not a game.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook recommends using the Send Dialog to invite friends to Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog